# Reactjs : Multiple Forms in tabs with validation

Tags: forms, validation, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Tab structure which will have same component in both the tabs
Component can add 2 fields at a time which are same whenever clicked on add
Form validations should happen for each newly added form on click
on the last form in last tab data from all the tabs in all the forms should be combined into single object

I want to know approach for this entire requirement.

P.S. Want to avoid usage of plugin

Tech Stack: React, Redux

Comment: Please provide some code.  It's hard to visual what want to do.

Comment: @whs.bsmith http://jsfiddle.net/rzv6Lrjh/93/

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to understand your question.  Please break it up into several sentences.  Use periods and capital letters.